# Idiomatic C# deserialization of custom binary files?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryfiles

Greetings,

What is the most idiomatic way of performing serialization/deserialization of binary custom formats? For example, how would you read a file with a set of headers specified in bytes (e.g. 4, 4, 16, 4, 8, 8, 4, 16) with no padding, with mixed integer/`byte[]` types?

In other words, how do you achieve the same level of control as in C when specifying a structure, without having to resort to sequences of Read/WriteBytes over a Stream?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to? What's wrong with the built-in [binary serialization functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b.aspx)?

Comment: @Cody that is useless if you don't control the format

Comment: @Marc: Yes, that's true. It wasn't clear to me from the question if that was the case. If it's an option, it's by far the most elegant one. Lots of programmers new to the .NET Framework aren't aware of this type of functionality being built-in.

Comment: Yes... I can't control the format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [article](http://dooba.net/2009/07/02/c-sharp-and-serializing-byte-arrays/) which illustrates one method to achieve this. But if you want ideomatic .NET then [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) is the way to go. If the format is not imposed and you have control over it you could also use [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) but what it produces is not interoperable.

Comment: Personally, I don't tend to use BinaryReader at all in this scenario; just raw Stream. By te time you have to cope with a prw-defined format that isn't the one BinaryReader wants to use for int, string, etc - it becomes pretty useless.

Comment: @Marc, so you are suggesting to read raw bytes directly from the stream and convert them to the underlying .NET data type?

Comment: Well, on a per-field level (as covered in my answer), sure. Bit with a buffer in the middle to reduce raw reads.

Comment: The referenced article returns 404 and is not available in wayback machine. Does anyone have an archived copy?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is a custom format, I would (and have) look to the XmlReader API; I would write a SomeFormatReader that rides a stream, and has a method for reading the next header. Once the caller has seen this return true (false meaning EOF), the caller should be able to access a property to check the data format that follows, and be able to call any of ReadInt32, ReadString, ReadSingle etc to handle each (following the rules of the binary format). In my case, my reader class also handles additional data buffering, etc.

You may then choose to wrap that with a secondary layer that uses type metadata and the newly-written reader to populate your object model (any of reflection, code-generation, meta-programming, etc). But creating a good standalone reader is he first hurdle.

Comment: That is probably the most straightforward way to implement it. But... it probably *isn't* ideomatic (even with instrospection and custom-attributes magic).

Comment: @Hugo - call the wrapper layer `SomeFormatSerializer`, new one up and call deserialize - feels like every .NET serializer I know...